# How to take a remote screenshot with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, screen-capture

I'm trying to figure out how to take remote screenshots over PowerShell from an administrator's account on the AD server to any computer on the network.

So far I've got the following.

```
 $ComputerName = '<THECOMPUTER>'

 copy-item "C:\Public\Software\Take-Screenshot.ps1" "\\$ComputerName\C$\"

 Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
     powershell -nop -c "C:\Take-Screenshot.ps1"
 }
```

`Take-Screenshot.ps1` is in from [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/eeff544a-f690-4f6b-a586-11eea6fc5eb8), but I've added the following to the bottom of the script to actually run the function.

```
Take-ScreenShot -screen -file C:\s.png -imagetype png
```

After the screenshot is taken, I'll copy it back to the host, but the problem is the picture is completely black.

I'm thinking this might be because the powershell is running the program, but there's not session attached to it, so there really is not screen??

Comment: Does first creating a remote PSSession help render a screenshot?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession?view=powershell-7

Comment: nope, still a blank image

Comment: You can try nircmd.exe from NirSoft.net
https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/savescreenshotfull.html, https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/savescreenshot.html it works for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I got this to work but it is a little involved. Works with multiple monitors.

You will need `Screenshot.ps1` on the remote PC, your trigger script and PSExec on local PC (Google).

```
# This is Screenshot.ps1
# Add types and variables
$File = "C:\Temp\Screenshot1.bmp"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Gather Screen resolution information
$Screen = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen
$Width = $Screen.Width
$Height = $Screen.Height
$Left = $Screen.Left
$Top = $Screen.Top

# Set bounds
$bitmap = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $Width, $Height

# Create Object
$graphic = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bitmap)

# Capture
$graphic.CopyFromScreen($Left, $Top, 0, 0, $bitmap.Size)

# Save
$bitmap.Save($File)
```

And then for the trigger script

```
#Setup Variables
$ComputerName = "ComputerName"
$PSExec = "C:\temp\tools\psexec.exe"

# Captures session details
$quser = (((query user /server:$ComputerName) -replace '^>', '') -replace '\s{2,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv)

# Takes screenshot of remote PC
&$PSExec -s -i $quser.ID "\\$ComputerName\" PowerShell -WindowStyle Hidden -File "C:\Temp\screenshot.ps1"
```

Comment: This is perfect.  I actually started to use psexec after I realized that it needed to attach to the session, but my attempts did not work well.  Added some code to select a specific user and transfer the screenshot.ps1 to the machine, but otherwise this is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: I did notice that a black box flashes on the screen for a fraction of a second when the PSExec is running even though the `-WindowStyle` is `Hidden` any way to not have that?

Comment: maybe a bit late - to get rid of the black box, you need to start the ps1 from something that is already invisible, like a vbs file