# How can I capture screenshots from remote windows machines?

Tags: windows, automation, screenshot, ui-automation

I know that it is technically not possible to capture screenshots when there is no active user session. The limitation is discussed in detail in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69075792/5976386). From my own experiments I found that if I'm connected to a machine via  RDP the screenshot works, but without that I get an "invalid handle" error. There's a similar question with an approved answer that uses [PSExec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59997279/5976386) but when I tried this out the screenshot was a black image.

I'm wondering if it's possible to force the machine to always have an active UI session with the use of some sort of dummy display hardware in combination with [AutoLogin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon)?

Would greatly appreciate answers that include specific hardware models and known to work with Windows 10.

Comment: You may want to ask this on superuser.com also.